# 10 random mySQL rows to different lines

Tags: php, mysql, select

Basically, I'm trying to get 10 random rows from MySQL and put them in my page. Getting those 10 random rows is easy.
The code that i have is:

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email order by rand()limit 10") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
 echo $row['Email'];
}
```

Now, echo gets those 10 rows and shows them to me, but I need to separate them, so I can put them in my site, one per div or whatever. Can anyone tell me how to separate those emails so I can put each of them in the place I need?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email order by rand()limit 10") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
 echo "<div>";
 echo $row['Email'];
 echo "</div>";
 }
```

Comment: I ment more like i get difrent echos, witch i can put where i need them

Comment: @AndisStrazdins So, you want different divs that you can echo wherever you want?

Comment: You could push them into an array, then just reference whatever array element you need/want. Both answers below should help with that.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this instance would be:

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

This will give you a array of random rows, You can then in your HTML do the following:

```
echo $data[0]['Email'];
```

Replacing the ID of the array with what random record you want..

Comment: Some considerations you should have are what if $data is not set. E.g. if there are less than 10 records. Then use if(isset($data[10]) prior to echoing out.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you want to do like that, it is a pretty bad design but however if that is what you want, all you have to do is:

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email order by rand()limit 10") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
{
  $email[] = $row;
}
```

now you have an array called `$email` with 10 elements in it. You can use it so, replacing field_name with whatever your email fields are:

```
<div><?php echo $email[0]['field_name'];?></div>
<lots of other html tags>
<div><?php echo $email[1]['field_name'];?></div>
<yet again more html tags>
<div><?php echo $email[2]['field_name'];?></div>
```